# How to find GPU size in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gpu

I found my GPU, by
`lspci | grep VGA` and found it to be `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland XT [Radeon HD 8670 / R7 250]`
 
I couldn't find my GPU size. Can someone help me with the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install utilities:

```
$ sudo apt install mesa-utils
```

Then check for memory size with:

```
$ glxinfo | egrep -i 'device|memory'
```

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and execute :

```
grep -i memory /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

The output is something like :

```
[     4.946] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes  

[     5.278] (II) NVIDIA: Using 3072.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory  

[     5.298] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
```

This example is from a NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 860M graphics card with 2 GB dedicated memory.